# Why might an AWS Lambda function run in docker-lambda, but crashes on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, executable

There are a set of Docker images available called [docker-lambda](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda) that aim to replicate the AWS Lambda environment as closely as possible. It's third party, but it's somewhat endorsed by Amazon and used in their [SAM Local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/test-sam-local.html) offering. I wrote a Lambda function that invokes an ELF binary, and it works when I run it in a `docker-lambda` container with the same runtime and kernel as the AWS Lambda environment. When I run the same function on AWS Lambda, the method mysteriously crashes with no output. I've given the function more RAM than the process could possibly use, and the dependencies are clearly there because the I know that it's not really possible to debug this without access to the binaries, but are there any common/possible reasons why this might be happening?

Additionally, are there any techniques to debug something like this? When running in Docker, I can add a `--cap-add SYS_PTRACE` flag to invoke a command using `strace` and see what might be causing an error. I'm not aware of an equivalent debugging technique on AWS Lambda.

Comment: Have you turned on logging to CloudWatch? Anything of use in there?

Comment: It might be useful if you can share some minimal example code - there could be various reasons why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Willing to bet that the AWS Lambda execution environment isn't playing nicely with that third party image. I've had no problems with Amazon's `amazon/aws-lambda-python:3.8` image.

Only other thing I can think of is tweaking the timeout of your lambda.